# What does powercf do on the Solaris file system or EMC storage?

Tags: linux, storage, solaris, emc, powerpath

When I run `powercf` command on my Solaris machine, what changes does this command do on the EMC storage, or on Solaris file system?

From the manual:

> DESCRIPTION
>   During system boot on Solaris  hosts,  the  powercf  utility configures  PowerPath  devices by scanning the HBAs for both single-ported and multiported storage  system  logical  devices.  (A multiported logical device shows up on two or more HBAs with the same storage system subsystem/device identity. The  identity  comes  from the serial number for the logical device.) For each storage system logical device found in the scan  of  the HBAs, powercf creates a corresponding emcpower device entry in the emcp.conf file, and it saves  a  primary path and an alternate primary path to that device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't make changes to the storage controller, it simply configures your multi-path driver. The translation of the description you posted is that it looks at the HBA (the fibre port on the server) and takes an inventory of all the LUNs it sees. If it sees the same LUN more than once, it configures them as multiple paths to the same device in the multipath driver config file.

Comment: ok so after I run the powercf -q command I get the: root@solaris10 ]#  /etc/powercf -q
Unexpected error occurred    ,   please advice what could be the problem ?

Comment: You neglected to mention in the question that you're getting errors. That said, you haven't provided enough information for anything more than a guess.